# Android:Error implementing typeface

Tags: android, typeface

I am making an app in which my class extends `RelativeLayout` and implements `OnClickListener` But my problem is that i am not able to set `TypeFace` in that its giving `Exception`

```
public class Viewnew extends RelativeLayout implements OnPageChangeListener {
Context mContext;
```

and when i use

```
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/trbuc.ttf");
```

I am getting exception at `mContext` and exception is as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15203): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
E/AndroidRuntime(15203): at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(15203):at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:214)
```

Comment: Add the full logcat, not just the line.

Comment: Are you implementing `typeface` with `CustomAdapter` class?

Comment: At first look I guess that you are not setting correctly the `mContext` while initializing your custom RelatiLayout, so check if it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **.otf** in place of **.ttf** and it worked.Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/trbuc.ttf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Code for that.

```
// Font path
String fontPath = "fonts/trbuc.ttf";

// text view label
TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewCustomFont);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: get Assets is not working with Relative layout because my class extends RelativeLAyout

Comment: Give your full activity code or class code & try my edited answer also.

Answer (score 0):

The context is obviously not the issue, as this is not a NullPointer.

The issue is the font file you are specifying. First, check that the path is correct. If it is, try loading a different font file and see if that works. Android is not able to load all fonts. It is picky. So if you can find a similar font, try that. I hope this ends up working for you.